# Is there a way to make virt-manager and xe to work at the same time?

Tags: xen, virt-manager

I followed instructions from this site: http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XCP_toolstack_on_a_Debian-based_distribution. The gist of it is basically to do an apt-get install xcp-xapi xcp-xe.

If I follow the "Workaround XAPI conflicts with XEND (Debian and Ubuntu)" part, which says to stop the xend and xendomains services from starting, the xe tools will work. But virt-manager won't. If the xend and xendomains services are started, virt-manager works but xe does not.

Is there a way to make both tools, virt-manager and xe, from working at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not currently possible to use Xapi (XCP's management daemon) and Libvirt at the same time. Xapi and Libvirt perform similar functions, and using Libvirt will just confuse Xapi and make your system unstable. (Note that xe is the command line interface to Xapi, and virt-manager is the interface to Xen or KVM through Libvirt).

Why do you want to use both Xapi and Libvirt at the same time?